# Output an array of objects with properties

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a function `displayTable(presidents)` which takes an array of president objects. Each president object has the properties name, tookOffice, leftOffice.

For each president I want to add a row to the table with id "presidents". Place the name in the first column, tookOffice in the second column, and leftOffice in the third column.

I keep getting `undefined` in the output

Here is my attempt - first the html

```
<div id="output">
    <table id="presidents">
        <tr>
            <th>President</th><th>Took office</th><th>Left office</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript

```
function  displayTable(presidents){
    for(var i = 1; i < presidents.length; i++){
      var row =  document.getElementById("presidents").insertRow(i);

        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        cell1.innerHTML = presidents.name;
        cell2.innerHTML = presidents.tookOffice;
        cell3.innerHTML = presidents.leftOffice;
    }
}
```

I know I'm close but cant figure it out

Comment: You are not specifying the index in the array               presidents[i].name
presidents[i].tookOffice
etc.

Comment: `presidents` should be `presidents[i]`, since it's an array of objects. What your input was (and how you defined `Presidents`), would be helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to access your array so simple

```
presidents[i].name;
presidents[i].tookOffice;
presidents[i].leftOffice;
```

Also I would recommend assembling your html fragments fully and then inserting the total fragment. The way you have it every insert is causing the browser to rerender, and that is even more expensive when dealing with tables. As is you have #rows*#cells*2+#rows rendering calls instead of 1 rendering call if you insert all the fragments at once.

Answer (score 0):

> I know I'm close but cant figure it out

Really close actually. Take a look at your code. When you set the innerHTML of your cells, you're referencing the entire presidents array, not specific entries. `cell1.innerHTML = presidents[i].name` Is what you want.

Check out developer tools in any modern browser to help you better debug what's going on in your browser. They all provide excellent javascript debuggers and tons of other features that'll help you in your web dev escapades.

**HTML Templates**

Now a better way to do what you're trying to do is via HTML Templates. With HTML templates, you can build a generic template of what you want your html to look like, then populate the template with data you generate in javascript or in an AJAX call. Below is an example of what you're trying to do using a template engine called Handlebars. There are plenty of excellent template engines out there, Handlebars being one of them.

http://handlebarsjs.com/
http://javascriptissexy.com/handlebars-js-tutorial-learn-everything-about-handlebars-js-javascript-templating/

```
<body>

</body>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://builds.handlebarsjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/handlebars-v2.0.0.js">

<script id="presidents-table-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <table id="presidents">
            <tr>
                <th>President</th><th>Took office</th><th>Left office</th>
            </tr>
            {{#each presidents}}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{name}}</td>
                    <td>{{tookOffice}}</td>
                    <td>{{leftOffice}}</td>
                </tr>
            {{/each}}
        </table>
    </div>
</script>

<script>

    var source = $("#presidents-table-template").html(),
        template = Handlebars.compile(source);

    var data = {
        "presidents" : [
            {
                tookOffice : 1990,
                leftOffice : 1994,
                name : "Ziggy"
            },
            {
                tookOffice : 1994,
                leftOffice : 1998,
                name : "Doyle"
            },
            {
                tookOffice : 1998,
                leftOffice : 2002,
                name : "Eduardo"
            },
        ]
    };

    var html = template(data);
    $("body").html(html);


</script>
```